# Sending data (not form) in wreq

Tags: http, haskell

Given a `curl` request of the form:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --data @somefile.xml http://httpbin.org/post
```

How can we do that in [`wreq`](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/)? I confirmed through echo from [httpbin](http://httpbin.org/post) that the data is sent as "data" - below is snippet from `httpbin` post echo:

```
  {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "<file-contents here sent by curl --data option>", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {...
  ...},
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "some_ip", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
  }
```

So, basically, given the data from the file as a `Text` or `String`, how do we make it `Postable` in `wreq` without using `form` or `multi-part` (unless `data` option of curl is just a `form` or `multi-part` post in disguise)? I am digging around `wreq` documentation but haven't yet found anything about that. I will very much appreciate pointers on how to do this. Setting `headers` and other things are pretty straight-forward in `wreq` as shown in the tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `post` with a `ByteString` directly?

Comment: @sclv, yep works. I found out that `Postable` class instances are documented under `Network.Wreq.Types` but only in older versions on hackage. That is why when searching for `Postable` instances in latest documentation, I found none :(

Comment: @sclv, you could post it as answer with link to relevant `Postable` instance documentation (even if old). Here is link to actual github source code with definition of `Postable` instances: https://github.com/bos/wreq/blob/master/Network/Wreq/Types.hs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `wreq` haddocks only [describe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html#g:4) *some* of the instances of `Postable`, there are in fact also `Postable` [instances](https://github.com/bos/wreq/blob/master/Network/Wreq/Types.hs#L56) for plain lazy and strict bytestrings, and those should let you stream raw data directly.